# Having array problems in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, for-loop

I am learning how to build apps and working with Swift for this project.

I had a buddy help me pull data in from a website and it looks like he created classes with variables and mapped them to certain extensions (IE "Username") so when I call the variable data such as profile I would call it.  The below uses luck_30 able to store "Stats.luck_30"

```
 luck_30.text = profile.luck_30
```

So inside one of my variables that is in this "Profile" class is setup into an array.  I can pull the array out of the class, but I can't seem to do for while statement replacing the [#] with a variable from the for command.

```
func aliveWorkers(profile: Profile) -> NSNumber{
    var myworkers : Array = profile.workers!

    //this test works and returns the proper value
    var testworker: NSNumber = myworkers[0].alive!
    println("The satus of the test worker is " + testworker.description)

    /* This code is giving error "Could not find member alive" it does not ifor var
    for ifor in myworkers{
        var thisworker: NSNumber = myworkers[ifor].alive! as NSNumber
    }
    */
    return 42
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `ifor` is not a counter, it is an actual object. You could do something like this:

```
for worker in myWorkers {
    let workerIsAlive = worker.alive!
}
```

Alternatively, if you need the index,

```
for i in 0 ..< myWorkers.count {
    let worker = myWorkers[i]
    let workerIsAlive = worker.alive!
}
```

If you need both:

```
for (i, worker) in enumerate(myWorkers) {
    let workerIsAlive = worker.alive!
}
```

And as a matter of style, I would stay away from `NSNumber` and use `Int` or `Bool` or whatever the data actually is. Also, it looks like the `alive` variable should not be optional, as you're unwrapping it everywhere. To avoid "mysterious" crashes later, you may want to think about making it a non-optional type.

Comment: Thanks.  The "For worker in mywokers" is working.  I am still learning, and will review my existing code for any of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

when using a `for in` loop, your loop variable isn't an index, its the objects you're looping through. so..

```
func aliveWorkers() {
    var myworkers = [1, 2, 3]

    //this test works and returns the proper value
    let testworker = myworkers[0]
    print("The satus of the test worker is \(testworker)")

    for ifor in myworkers {
        print(ifor)
    }
}
```

Notice a few things... you don't need to use `+` to concatenate those strings. you can just use string interpolation. `\(variable)` inserts the value of `variable` in the string.

Try to use `let` instead of `var` when you don't change the variable. You don't need to explicitly define type on variables either.